# how to remove attribute from html tags in java

Tags: java, html

I wanted to remove the particular attribute from anchor tag:

```
<a  id="nav-askquestion" style="cursor:default" href="/questions">
```

output:-

```
<a   href="/questions">
```

through java program

Comment: I think OP wants to remove all attributes except `href`

Answer (score 4):

we use [htmlparser](http://htmlparser.sourceforge.net/) for this kind of job

you can parse and modify nodes with this untested snipplet:

```
NodeVisitor visitor = new NodeVisitor() {
    public void visitTag(Tag tag) {
            tag.removeAttribute("id");
            tag.removeAttribute("style");
    }

};

Parser parser = new Parser(...);
parser.visitAllNodesWith(visitor);
```

Answer (score 2):

This little snippet will do the trick.

Ask me if you need some questions about the Regex

```
public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String htmlFragment ="<a  id=\"nav-askquestion\" style=\"cursor:default\" href=\"/questions\">";
        String attributesToRemove = "id|style";

        System.out.println(htmlFragment);
        System.out.println(cleanHtmlFragment(htmlFragment, attributesToRemove));
    }

    private static String cleanHtmlFragment(String htmlFragment, String attributesToRemove) {
        return htmlFragment.replaceAll("\\s+(?:" + attributesToRemove + ")\\s*=\\s*\"[^\"]*\"","");    
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

People might suggest to use regex, but [beware](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags), you can use an XML Parser.

Comment: While I agree that regexes bring their own set of issues, no, you can't use an XML parser.  HTML != XML.  Even the example the OP gave demonstrates that.